# Is there a way to replace a value of a variable in row of if a certain condition is met and repeat this for a whole data frame?

Tags: r

I have data frame like this

```
main <- round(runif(100,min = 1, max = 5 ))
a1 <- rep(1, 100)
a2 <- rep(1, 100)
a3 <- rep(1, 100)
a4 <- rep(1, 100)
a5 <- rep(1, 100)

df <- data.frame(main, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
```

I want to replace the values of a1 - a5 based on conditions for every row in the data frame.
The conditions are:

If main == 1 replace a1 with 0

If main == 2 replace a2 with 0

If main == 3 replace a3 with 0

If main == 4 replace a4 with 0

If main == 5 replace a5 with 0

But if a value is changed in a row the other should not be touched and stay the same.
The result should look something like this:

```
main a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
1    0  1  1  1  1
4    1  1  1  0  1
3    1  1  0  1  1
5    1  1  1  1  0
3    1  1  0  1  1
...
```

I have tried some loops with if statements but I can't get I working.

Could someone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `row/column` indexing

```
df[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$main)] <- 0
head(df)
#  main a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
#1    5  1  1  1  1  0
#2    1  0  1  1  1  1
#3    4  1  1  1  0  1
#4    4  1  1  1  0  1
#5    1  0  1  1  1  1
#6    2  1  0  1  1  1
```

---

We can subset the columns by numeric index or names

```
nm1 <- paste0("a", 1:5)
```

Or

```
nm1 <- names(df)[2:6]
```

Or

```
nm1 <- 2:6

df[nm1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$main)] <- 0
```

---

If we need a `ifelse`, then

```
df[nm1] <- lapply(1:5, function(i) ifelse(df$main == i,  0, df[[i + 1]]))
```

Comment: My original data frame has a lot more columns which I do not need in this specific circumstance but I do need them for some other calculations. So this code doesn't work for me. Is there a way to this in an ifelse statement or something? Something which specifically calls the names of the columns.

Comment: @C.Toni  You can just subset the columns as I showed. here,  Lets say'  you want to do only 2:6, `df[2:6][cbin(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$main)] <- 0`

Comment: Okay, thanks. With a little transformation of my data frame I could do this. But I am really curious about how this would work with an if statement. I am new to programming, and I am trying to teach myself. So it would be cool if you could show me how this is done and I can learn from what I have done wrong in my code.

Comment: @C.Toni  That can be done, but it would be very inefficient

Comment: I am just trying to learn and showing me an if statement which is (for me) more complex than the basic   if (x = 1) {print("true")} else {print("false") could maybe help me improve in understanding the r language. But don't worry if you don't have the time. You helped me with your answers above. Thank you.

Comment: @C.Toni  Updated with a `ifelse` as it is vectorized.  `if/else` is not vectorized and this would be double loops

Answer (score 1):

For `inplace` replacement You could do:

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), df$main + 1)] <- 0

head(df)
  main a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
1    4  1  1  1  0  1
2    5  1  1  1  1  0
3    2  1  0  1  1  1
4    1  0  1  1  1  1
5    4  1  1  1  0  1
6    3  1  1  0  1  1
```

for not `inplace` replacement, you could do:

```
 replace(df, cbind(1:100, df$main + 1), 0)
```

Comment: using `main` only in `replace(df, cbind(1:100, main + 1), 0)` makes a bit shorter :)

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding that is an assumption that main will be on the working environment or rather the dataframe is `attach`ed.